# Jmeter Uncaught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record REST requests with "http(s) test script recorder". It's working properly and record the request until i keep "Capture HTTP Headers" checked.  Since I want to keep header common with some variable throughout requests and wanted to put dynamic parameter I don't want http header to be recorded everytime.

To do so, I remove that checkbox "Capture HTTP Headers", now none of my requests are getting recorded. And application is throwing exception

I am using https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf to record the requests.

ERROR - jmeter.JMeter:

### Uncaught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException

at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.replaceValues(ProxyControl.java:1275)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.ProxyControl.deliverSampler(ProxyControl.java:567)
at
org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:291)

Comment: Hi, what version of JMeter are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged the bug with jmeter issue tracker. 
They have suggested a solution to recompile the source with these 2 file changes.

> jmeter/trunk/src/protocol/http/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/proxy/Proxy.java
>   jmeter/trunk/xdocs/changes.xml

Actual Bug https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58453

Thanks,